# Display selected ListView item into TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

i'm new in stackoverflow as i'm new in android studio, i'm not good at code but i'm trying to,i know this is silly question maybe, but still i need help

so let's get to the point
so i have listview to select ".txt" file and get content inside of it, i manage to get code from internet(forget the source) to select ".txt" file but i don't know how to display it in my TextView

so here's the code for my XML

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/opendialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Browse" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="input"
    android:id="@+id/result"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see i have TextView with ID "result" i want to put my selected .txt file and display it content into that TextView

this is my onClick method, this method only select the item

```
dialog_ListView = (ListView)   dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
            dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,   int position, long id) {
                    File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));
                    if(selected.isDirectory()) {
                        ListDir(selected);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,      selected.toString() + "selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

my question is, how to getText from .txt item that i have selected

Comment: Can you explain what do you want please? You want when you click on an item on your Listview show it on TextView as a text?

Comment: Yes, that what i want

Comment: Take a look my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you'll have to create an object of `TextView`

```
TextView result;
```

In your `onCreate()` you'll have to `findViewById()` as follows :

```
result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
```

Then in your `dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` you can get the text from an item clicked doing this :

```
String SelectedItem = (dialog_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Then you can display the text doing this :

```
result.setText(SelectedItem);
```

Other way you can do is if you want the text on `textFolder` you can simply do that  :

```
String SelectedItem = textFolder.getText();
result.setText(SelectedItem);
```

### EDIT

This is an option to how you can do it.

First you'll have to follow the first steps to create the result `TextView` once you do this you continue doing this inside your `onItemClick()` :

```
String path = selected.toString();
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
result.setText(filename);
```

It will show you the text of your file, for example `colors.json`.

### FINAL EDIT

Ok, now I got what you exactly want!

Take a look, I've this method to read from a `File`

```
public String readFromFile(String path) {

   //Get the text file
    File file = new File(path);
    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //This is the text from the file
    return text.toString();
}
```

Then you simply add this two lines inside your `onItemClick()`

```
String path = selected.toString();
result.setText(readFromFile(path));
```

And there we go, it works! :)

Comment: you explain so well, but since im new in android, im still hardly implement what u mean, so is it something like this? http://1drv.ms/1ZjM2qg

Comment: Whats wrong with that?

Comment: have u already click the link that i provided?

Comment: Yes I did whats wrong with that?

Comment: Also try get(position)

Comment: **"String SelectedItem = (dialog_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position));"**, it says " incompatible type, require java.lang.string but found java.lang.object

Comment: there's another problem, how to get the position and also it's said that onClick method never use

Comment: hey i manage to set the text into TextView, but the problem is it only show the path of .txt instead of the text inside .txt, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @MirzaChilman See my edit please

Comment: where did u edit it? kindly check the this link 1drv.ms/1ZjM2qg
i doesn't crashes on me

Comment: Check my answer, I've edited it

Comment: Wait wait wait.... you don't want to show for example `exam.txt`?

Comment: ok let's make it clear haha

imagine i have "example.txt", inside that "example.txt" theres a string (text), let's say there's a word "stackoverflow"

how do i display the word "stackoverflow"(which is inside example.txt) in my TextView?

Comment: all i can do is displaying the path in my TextView rather than displaying the word "stackoverflow"

Comment: OMG dude, u just give me an A on my cryptography courses, thanks a lot, sweet

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding ^^